# could not find symbol thread.sleep

Tags: java, compiler-errors, cannot-find-symbol

Why am I getting an error in this code please help me out.
Error is coming that

> could not find symbol thread.sleep

here is the code:

```
  import java.util.Date;
  class Date_Time
    {
      public static void main(String[] args)
      throws Throwable
     {
          while(true)
          {
             Date_Time d= new Date_Time();
             System.out.print(d);
             thread.sleep(500);
             System.out.println("\r");
             thread.sleep(500);
          }
      }
    }
```

Comment: WHY ARE YOU SHOUTING???

Comment: it should be `Thread.sleep(500);`

Comment: THANKS BUT AFTER USING T instead of t m not getting o/p in proper way its coming lyk this 1@bedef2...

Comment: are you trying to print the actual date every second? take a look at my post

Comment: @MohammadAdil thanks for that but could uh please tell me where m wrong with this code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java it's `Thread.sleep(500);` with capital letter.

> Edit

`Date_Time` is your class. If you want to print the date you need to use `Date` library

```
Date d = new Date();
System.out.print(d);
```

Comment: THANKS BUT AFTER USING T instead of t m not getting o/p in proper way its coming lyk this 1@bedef2...

Comment: @ShakhKhan What are you expecting to see?

Comment: time and date thats it

Comment: i want it to display mah current date and time but its something different

Comment: i already impoeted Date package ..mah program 1st line check it out..

Comment: @ShakhKhan The import is not the point. You need to use `Date`, not your own class.

Comment: thanks a lot brother :)

Answer (score 0):

**d** is a `class`, so if you print a class you will get the tostring representation of it, so  modify the class,(override the toString method and return what you need to from it)

```
import java.util.Date;
class Date_Time{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        while(true){
            Date_Time d= new Date_Time();
            System.out.print(new Date());
            thread.sleep(500);
            System.out.println("\r");
            thread.sleep(500);
        }
    }
}
```